# USB Composite device: how to make two virtual serial ports independent?

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc

We have an embedded device (STM32) that connects to the PC via one unique USB.
The USB connection offers two virtual serial ports.
Device description is:

```
0xEF,     /*bDeviceClass*/
0x02,     /*bDeviceSubClass*/
0x01,     /*bDeviceProtocol*/
```

and interfaces description are

```
0x02,     /* bFunctionClass: CDC */
0x02,     /* bFunctionSubClass */
0x01,     /* bFunctionProtocol */
```

Tested on Windows, we can send and receive data over the two virtual serial ports.
However the constraint is that both virtual serial port must be opened for data transmission working. It means that we need one session of Docklight (or Putty) per virtual serial port for data to flow from the embedded device to the PC.

Once one of the sessions of Docklight (or Putty) is closed, no more data is flowing on the other session. The code is still running, but nothing goes out of the embedded device.

In that case, on very low level, CTR of USB interrupt status register (USB_ISTR) is always 0, so the code to send data from the embedded device is not executed.

Does anyone know how to make those two virtual serial port independent ?

Thanks

Comment: I have device which has 3 CDC ports. But the descriptor is much more complicated than the "normal" one.

Comment: Descriptions in the question are only an extract of what is needed ;-)

Comment: @0___________ can you share such descriptor as an answer?

Comment: The descriptors are probably not the problem.  I would be more suspect of the code you wrote or the code that you are using.  Maybe you have some blocking loops in there that wait for something to happen on one of the ports before going on to service transactions from another port.  Note that if the serial port is closed, Windows will not necessary poll your device for any IN data on that endpoint, so if you had a blocking loop that was trying to send data to the computer, it might take forever.  You should look at what parts of your code and running when the device is malfunctioning.